# Take over all links -- except certain class (.not?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm currently taking over any links on the page that begin with "users":

```
$('a[href^="/users/"]').live('click', function(event) {
```

...however, this is a little greedy.  I want to exclude any links to "stuff" that are NOT with the "versions" class.  I tried:

```
$('a[href^="/users/"]').not('div.versions a').live('click', function(event) {
```

...but this breaks the whole block.  My next guess it is breaking because of "live" -- with the way events trickle up.

Any ideas?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Breaks the whole block as in the event never fires when you click any of them?

Comment: The reason for this is that jQuery relies on the correct selector for `.live()` to work. When a click event is received, it compares the elements to the selector. When you use `.not('div.versions a')`, the selector ends up looking like `a[href^="/users/"].not(div.versions a)`, which doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try merging `not` in the main selector:

```
$('a[href^="/users/"]:not(div.versions a)').live('click', function(event) {
```

Check here as well: [.not() with .live() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635471/not-with-live-not-working), seems to be the same problem.