# jQuery Traversing + Live Event Handlers

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I'm having some issues with attaching live event handlers to particular rows.

---

**What I have and what I'm after:**

I have some HTML that will be generated *dynamically after page load* as follows:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="bonus"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

I would like to have two `click` events:

1. One for rows that aren't a "bonus row"
2. One for rows that have a "bonus row" after them

---

**What I've tried and the problem:**

However, I cannot work out how to use a selector to select "element that has a particular element after it" (i.e. a "previous" selector). As such, the best I can arrive at is:

1. Rows that aren't a "bonus row": `$('tr:not(:has(.bonus))')`
2. Rows that have a "bonus row" after them: `$('tr + tr:has(.bonus)').prev()`

This is all well and good, except whenever I use the `live()` method on a jQuery object that was obtained through traversal, rather than pure selection i.e.

```
$('tr:has(.bonus)').prev().live('click', function() {
   alert('hello');
});
```

I get this error:

> uncaught exception: Syntax error,
>   unrecognized expression: )

---

**The issue as an even more minimal example:**

I was hoping this was localised to some script I am using, but I've isolated this to a minimal jsFiddle example which still replicates the issue for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/ptvrA/

HTML:

```
<div></div>
<div id="target"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#target').prev().live('click', function () {
   alert('f');
});
```

It seems from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635471/not-with-live-not-working) that this is a known limitation of `live`.

---

**My workarounds**

For reference, my workarounds are either:

1. Mark the rows that have a "bonus row" after them in some way
2. Bind the `click` to all rows, and do a check to see if there is a "bonus row" after them within the handler.

But if I can get a "nicer" solution, even out of curiosity in case I run into this problem in a different situation, I'd appreciate it.

Cheers

Comment: What's interesting is if you use the selector `$('tr:has(.bonus)').prev('tr')` it doesn't cause the syntax error...  but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I'd just use your second idea and bind click to all rows, then check to see if next row has a bonus td in it, like this:

```
$('tr:not(:has(.bonus))').live('click', function () {
    if ($(this).next().children('td').hasClass('bonus')) {
       alert('next row has bonus td');
    }
    else {
       alert('next row does not have bonus td');
    }
});
```

fiddle located here: http://jsfiddle.net/7gdqc/2/

I don't think there's a pure selector way to do it, and this isn't really a workaround - I'd call it a valid solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi Christian, that's what I've gone with so good to see I wasn't insane for heading that direction!

Comment: Actually I just edited it so that you only bind the click to rows that don't have a bonus (like your example), if you don't need those rows handled. Sometimes you just have to do things without pure selectors :p

Answer (score 2):

```
$('tr + tr:has(.bonus) ~ tr') //for row whose next sibling is a bonus row
```

Will do what you want with the .live method.

For all the people who get here in the future using google.

```
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: )
```

That is happening because .live() uses the original selector that was given to the first call in the jQuery chain. It doesn't no consider additional methods used after the initial $('selector').

Comment: Hi wewals, yes this works (well actually i think the `$(e.target).parent('tr')` bit should error in use but the idea is sound) and is already mentioned in my workarounds. Doesn't really solve the original problem though (as this ends up binding click events to all `tr` elements, even if we do filter within the handler).

Comment: However, it's worth mentioning that live only binds a single event handler, ever. It's an event bound to the body that does an e.target check very much like the one that I wrote to check against the first selector passed into the jquery object to which the .live call is appended. So you're not going to be binding to every tr element. This is the reason .live is recommended to heavily.

Comment: I've changed my answer to not include the workaround. It should work with the selector I've done should work with live.